# Reset only the time and convert it to utc in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time

I saw many post where they are setting the date and time taking the instace.now(). However my requirement is little bit different.

I have the UTC time like - **2020-05-12T12:48:00**  I want to set only the time to "00:30:00"(12:30 AM) and my time zone is Ameria/NewYork?

My question is how can I set time only to 00:30:00 (12:30 AM)? and when i convert this to UTC i need to get the below results

> input: **2020-05-12T6:30:00**
>
> output :  Without day light saving : **2020-05-12T4:30:00** With
>   daylight saving : **2020-05-12T5:30:00**

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: my time zone is America/New_York

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2:**

> I assume today's 12:30 AM is equal to UTC 04:30:00.

You are correct. To obtain that result we need to convert *from New York time to UTC* after having forced the time to be 12:30 AM. It’s the opposite conversion compared to my previous answer.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    LocalTime wantedNyTime = LocalTime.of(0, 30); // 12:30 AM

    String utcDateTimeString = "2020-05-12T06:30:00";
    OffsetDateTime newUtcTime = LocalDateTime.parse(utcDateTimeString)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)               // Interpret in UTC
            .atZoneSameInstant(zone)                // Convert to time zone
            .with(wantedNyTime)                     // set time to 00:30
            .toOffsetDateTime()
            .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC); // Convert back to UTC

    System.out.println(newUtcTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
```

Output is:

> 2020-05-12T04:30:00

Today and yesterday summer time (DST) is in effect in New York (since March 8). To see what happens during the standard time part of the year:

```
    String utcDateTimeString = "2020-02-29T03:12:00";
```

> 2020-02-28T05:30:00

### Original answer

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    LocalTime wantedUtcTime = LocalTime.of(9, 30); // 09:30

    String utcDateTimeString = "2020-05-12T12:48:00";
    ZonedDateTime newUtcTime = 
        LocalDateTime                   // Represents a date and time-of-day, but lacks the context of a time zone or offset.
            .parse(utcDateTimeString)   // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)   // Returns a `OffsetDateTime`. 
            .with(wantedUtcTime)        // Returns another `OffsetDateTime`, per immutable objects.
            .atZoneSameInstant(zone);   // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.

    System.out.println(newUtcTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
```

Output:

> 2020-05-12T05:30:00

Edit:

> My time zone is - America/New_York

What the code does: It parses the string and interprets it in UTC since you said that it was in UTC. It sets the time to 09:30 (a little over 3 hours earlier in this case) because this will give us the time of day in the end that you want. Finally it converts to the chosen time zone, which subtracts the 4 hours to give the 05:30 that you want during summer time.

Here’s what happens with a date in the standard time part of the year:

```
    String utcDateTimeString = "2020-02-29T03:12:00";
```

> 2020-02-29T04:30:00

Comment: When i use the above code. with following time zone i get wrong results. My time zone is - America/New_York

Comment: I verified this, Here my requirement is only to make sure that what ever the time is i need to rest that to 12:30 AM. When i convert this to UTC i need the proper result in UTC

Comment: not really!! I assume today's 12:30 AM is equal to UTC 04:30:00. When i run your code i should have got 04:30 but it returned me 05:30.